# Losing pixels when scaling a set of coordinates by integer division

Tags: c#, integer, double, pixel, mousemove

I'm trying make a program, that moves your mouse by certain amount of pixels.
Coordinates of moves are set in "dx" and "dy" integers and are taken from an array of integers, for example `{ -85, 75 }, { 0, 67 }, { 33, 57 }, { 58, 48 }` and so on - there is plenty of these movements.

The array of these coordinates is set for mouse sensitivity = `0,25`

What i need to do is convert it to mouse sensitivity that is equals to `1`

In order to get 4 times smaller moves I tried to divide values (integers) I get from the array (`{-85, 75}`) and divide every move by 4.

The whole problem is that when i divide, let's say `-85 / 4` it leaves me with a remainder **WHICH MEANS IM LOSING PIXELS** each move.

It could be stored in double, but mouse movement can be only expressed in ints since we can't move by half of a pixel

Any solution to this? If i lose 3 or 4 pixels on each shot it wouldn't be a big deal, but since it stacks on its getting worse and worse.

Here is a piece of my code that is resposible for moving the mouse:

`

```
private void _MoveMouse()
        {
            while (appRunning)
            {
                if (Utility.bGetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton))
                {
                    int[,] pattern = Current_Table().Item1; //Current_Table() returns table of (x, y) coordinates in integers and sleep time in integer that is used to sleep the thread
                    int sleep = Current_Table().Item2;

                    if (_ENABLED == true)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                        {
                            int dx = pattern[i, 0]/4; //leaves a remainder from X coordinates that can not be stored in integer.
                            int dy = pattern[i, 1]/4; //leaves a remainder from Y coordinates that can not be stored in integer

                            int dx_rest = dx % 4; //the remainder from X
                            int dy_rest = dy % 4; //the remainder from Y


                            //MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(pattern[i,0] + " " + pattern[i,1]));

                            Utility.Move(dx, dy );

                            Thread.Sleep(sleep);

                            if (Utility.bGetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LButton)== false)
                            { 
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }`
```

Comment: Let me try that again. Welcome to integer division, it's a pain. Often, the way around the issues you are facing involve doing all the calculations using floating point numbers. That way, the errors don't accumulate. When you need an integer, convert your actual number (a float, or a double) to an int. You should probably use bankers round (aka, round to even). That way, you minimize error

Comment: I think it's more a mouse movement method issue, because its moving by pixels, so it can't move by 0,3 pixel :/

Comment: Right, but if you track things accurately (without accumuting error) and you decide you need to move 0.3 pixels (since that rounds to zero). Then you don't move. Then, the next time around, maybe you are to move 0.4 pixels in the same direction. When you compare where you.are with where you want to be, you realize that the diff is 0.7. So you move one pixel. You need to keep two sets of books, on in floating point and on in integers. Getting it right is a pain. But it can be done